# Accessing fields of children classes within an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, foreach, iterator

I am testing inheritance within Java, I have an abstract class with two fields and three extended classes with their own fields. In another class I instantiate and add objects of the class in an array, but I am not sure of how I can access the fields of the subclasses, the array is of the main abstract class:

here is the complete code of the abstract class and one of the extended classes:

```
public abstract class MusicRecord {
    private String type;
    private int length;
  
    public MusicRecord(String type, int length){
    this.type = type;
    this.length = length;
    }
  
    public String getType(){
    return type;
    }
    public int getLength(){
    return length;
    }
  
    public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
    }
  
    public void setLength(int length){
        this.length = length;
    }
  
    }
```

```
public class CD extends MusicRecord {
    private int price;
    private String title;
  
    public CD(String type, int lenght, String title, int price){
        super(type, lenght);
        this.price = price;
        this.title = title;
    }
  
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return "MusicRecord: " + super.getType();
    }
    public int getLenght(){
        return super.getLength();
    }
  
    public void setPrice(int price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Store {
  
    public static void main(String args[]){
    CD cd1 = new CD("Jaz", 34, "Music 44", 19);
    SD sd1 = new SD("R&B", 45, "Lova is never Lost!!", 21);
    BlueRay br1 = new BlueRay("Hell on Earth", 25, "HipHop", 40);

  
    MusicRecord[] mr = {cd1, sd1, br1,
        new CD("House", 40, "22 Is the Age", 22),
        new SD("Garage", 60, "Boom Boom Boommm", 14),
        new BlueRay("is it time to love", 18, "R&B", 35)};
                  
    for(MusicRecord r : mr){
        System.out.println("Type: " + r.getType() + "\nLength: " + r.getLength());
    }
}
```

how do I get the fields from the subclass/es?

Comment: Why do you want to get the fields from the subclasses? I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to use polymorphism to print something specific per subclass -> create a method which gets overwritten. Do you just want to access the fields specifically -> use `instanceof` and casts

Comment: If you mean like calling `getPrice` on an object declared as a `MusicRecord` but that at runtime is actually a `CD`, you'll have to cast it, as in `((CD)r).getPrice()`, but I have to wonder why `MusicRecord` itself doesn't have a `getPrice` method to begin with.

Comment: Also this looks like an abuse of subclasses. Because every subclass looks the same, i.e. have the same fields. -> `MusicRecord` should be a concrete class, and you should be able to provide a type e.g. `enum RecordType { CD, SD, BLUE_RAY }` yourself, when creating an instance of a record

Comment: hi, this is just a test and I want to know if there is a way to access the fields of the objects in the subclasses that have been added in the given array. The subclasses will have their own fields that do not match the fields of other subclasses. I have named them the same but lets say that they are different. casting would give me an error, but I have sorted this out with an if statement with instanceof..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ow I can access the fields of the subclasses, the array is of the main abstract class:

The java type system is covariant. (Except in generics, where variance is selectable, and by default, **invariant**). For the rest of this answer, you need to be aware that:

- java.lang.Integer extends java.lang.Number
- java.lang.Double extends java.lang.Number
- java.lang.Number extends java.lang.Object

Covariance means that you can take an expression whose type is `Integer`, and use it where a `Number` is required: Any subtype is fine when a supertype is required. (Invariance means that only an expression of specifically type Number will do, and contravariance is the reverse: If Integer is required, either Number or Object is also fine).

Thus:

```
Number[] x = new Number[2];
x[0] = new Integer(5);
x[1] = new Double(10.0);
```

is all fine.

That also means, if you flip it around, that if an expression is of type Number, then it may well be some subtype of Number. Given that Number is abstract, this is in, fact, **a guarantee**! No instances of Number itself can exist, only instances of subclasses of it.

You can use instanceof and casting and pattern matching to work with this:

NB: This uses new java features introduced in java15!

```
Object[] x = new Object[2];
x[0] = "hello";

if (x[0] instanceof String y) {
    y.toLowerCase();
}
```

Here we first check if `x[0]` is a String (it might be. It could also be an Integer, or a FileInputStream, or a `com.sun.internal.impl.HttpRequestImpl$1` - covariance means that the actual type of things can be, and usually is, some internal detail that isn't guaranteed and can change between java versions and implementations). **If** it is a string, then for all code that can only be reached if it was (here that'd be the insides of that if block), `y` as a variable exists, and contains a reference to the exact same object, but this time typed as a string, and thus you can freely invoke string methods on it, such as `.toLowerCase()`.

If you're not on JDK15 yet, the 'old' way is:

```
if (x[0] instanceof String) {
    String y = (String) x[0];
    y.toLowerCase();
}
```

This is called the cast operator, and it is merely a type assertion: If `x[0]` is indeed a String, then this code does nothing. It's as if you wrote (`String y = x[0];`, except that won't compile, but the effect is the same: y is now pointing at the same thing `x[0]` points at, the cast merely tells the compiler you know this is asserting type, and adds a runtime test).

If on the other hand `x[0]` is not pointing at some instance of j.l.String, that line will throw a ClassCastException.

Thus you could do something like:

```
int totalPrice = 0;
for (MusicRecord mr : records) {
    if (mr instanceof CD cd) totalPrice += cd.price;
}
```

NB: The right way to write that in java is `Cd`, not `CD`. By convention, of course - the java spec lets you write whatever you want. But if you want your code to interact well with libraries and be readable to other java coders, it's a good idea to follow the established conventions, and these state that you titlecase all the things, even acronyms that are, in ordinary writing, rendered in all-caps. DvdPlayer, not DVDPlayer. Cd, not CD. While you're at it, direct field access is not okay by convention - make getters instead. Should be `cd.getPrice()`.

Comment: hi again rzwitserloot, that actually answered my question, I was reading all the documentation I could find but there was no detailed explanation to point out this detailed info that you posted. so thank you, I keep in mind your helpful suggestions on naming conventions too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lino,rzwitserloot and Federico klez Culloca, I was able to solve the issue with the following addition.

```
for(MusicRecord r : mr){
      if(r instanceof CD){
        System.out.println("Type: " + r.getType() + "\nLength: " + r.getLength() + "\nTitle: " + ((CD)r).getTitle() + "\nPrice: " + ((CD)r).getPrice() + "\n ***************");
      } else if (r instanceof SD){
        System.out.println("Type: " + r.getType() + "\nLength: " + r.getLength() + "\nTitle: " + ((SD)r).getTitle() + "\nPrice: " + ((SD)r).getPrice() + "\n ***************");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Type: " + r.getType() + "\nLength: " + r.getLength() + "\nTitle: " + ((BlueRay)r).getTitle() + "\nPrice: " + ((BlueRay)r).getPrice() + "\n ***************");
      }
```